Specify YAML nested entries without indents
In Javascript, it's possible to do this:
const myObj = {
  key1: val1
  key2: val2
  ...
}

myObj.keyWithLongVal = { ... }

and the resulting json would be (see https://paste.debian.net/plain/1338706)
{
  key1: val1,
  key2: val2,
  ...
  keyWithLongVal = { ... },
}

I'm looking for a similar behavior in YAML. My goal is to keep all the YAML file within 80 columns regardless of how deep the nested content is.
very:
  heavily:
    nested:
      obj: lorem

very.prose: |
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
  eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Is this possible in yaml?
related question: How to flatten the YAML structure (List/Map)

Json doesn't care about indentation (or lack thereof).  YAML does, but you could use single-space indentation to minimize how much shifting is done to the right.

"and the resulting json would be" - that is not valid JSON at all

Are you writing the YAML by hand? Or are you generating it with a program?

@Bergi "Not valid JSON". This is what I meant: https://paste.debian.net/plain/1338706 - yes, I'm using YAML as a simple personal plaintext database.

YAML is designed such that any valid JSON is valid YAML, so if you have valid JSON that meets your constraints, you can say "yeah, this same byte stream is YAML".

You can have YAML without indentation, just use flow style:
{
very: {
heavily: {
nested: {
obj: lorem
}}},
very.prose: "\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy\n\
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam\n\
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita\n\
kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\n"
}

Not sure if that's what you're searching for. Mind that by default, a multi-line double-quoted scalar will parse a line break as a space. I have used \n here to insert a line break, then escaped the line end with \ to prevent it from becoming a space. A double-quoted scalar is the only scalar form in YAML that you can break at any position and therefore what you need if you must stay within a certain column limit.
Be aware that very.prose is an own key that has no relation to the very key. A dot is not a special character in YAML.
If your keys become too long to fit into 80 characters, use explicit keys:
{
? "a very long key which you need to break up into two lines to\n
prevent it from going over the 80 character limit"
: "some value"
}


YAML has a concept called anchors which might be useful here. It will change your document structure a bit, but nothing that isn't easily handled.
anchors:
  foo: &myanchor
    'Lorem ipsum ...'

very:
  heavily:
    nested:
      obj: *myanchor

Which when deserialised (and then re-serialised as JSON) becomes:
{
    "anchors": {
        "foo": "Lorem ipsum ..."
    },
    "very": {
        "heavily": {
            "nested": {
                "obj": "Lorem ipsum ..."
            }
        }
    }
}

As you can see the anchored source object remains in the deserialised object. So if you wanted to get rid of the anchors, then you just need to delete the anchors key from the map.
You can anchor any object (maps, lists, strings, numbers, etc...). You can also anchor both values in a map (like above) or items in a list. eg.
- &another_anchor 123
- *another_anchor

Which is loaded as [123, 123].
